# How to be absolutely sure that socket.io is working?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Normally, in order to know that it's started, there's a message in Node that says "info - socket.io started". However, for some reason, I'm not getting it. Could be a version thing.

So is there another way to know if my socket is up and listening?

Comment: Can you please provide the code that you are talking about?

Comment: what you mean with `i´m not getting it` ? Did you tried to sync some data witch sockets, for example? Please add your code here!

Answer (score 0):

Have you recently updated Socket.io from version 0.9 to 1.x? The default values for log reporting changed with version 1.0, and it's less verbose by default.
See the [upgrade](http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/#log-differences) documentation.

PS: If you upgraded Socket.io and you didn't even realize it, then it's because your "package.json" file does not lock versions. I'd strongly advise AGAINST using `*` as version: always be more specific, locking the versions *at least* to the minor version (as per [semver](http://semver.org/)). For example:

```
// In package.json, under "dependencies":

// NOT SAFE: this always gets the last version, which may have some breaking change (as per semver, with version X.Y.Z, changes in X allow breaking changes in APIs)
"socket.io": "*"

// POSSIBLY SAFE: this does not update to the new major version, so API compatibility *should* be always maintained (however, it's not 100% safe too, to be used carefully)
"socket.io": "1.x"

// SAFE: this allows updates that contain bug fixes and minor additions; API-compatibility should always be guaranteed
"socket.io": "1.0.x"
"socket.io": "1.0.*" // equivalent
"socket.io": "~1.0.4" // equivalent
```

Comment: Here's what says in my package.json: "socket.io": "^1.3.5" so I guess it's safe.